# gif doesn't play when button is pressed PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

My goal is to play a gif when a button is pressed, but for some reason it doesn't work. I think it worth mentioning that the button can stop the animation with `self.movie.stop()` but it doesn't work at all with `self.movie.start()`, I'm sure that the button does call the function becuase of the print statement I've put in, but `self.movie.start()` doesn't work

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie

class APP(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)

        self.movie = QMovie(r'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\de.gif')
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QSize(300,225))

        self.btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.strt)
        self.btn.setGeometry(100,130,150,50)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)

        self.show()

    def strt(self):
        print("Button pressed")
        self.movie.start()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = APP()
app.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you're able to stop the animation, but then how do you know that since it isn't started?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the animation does start if i put ```self.movie.start()``` in the main block, however once i put inside the ```strt()```function it won't start like I want it to.

Comment: I'm guessing that if you use `self.movie.jumpToFrame(0)` as per the proposed answer, it will work on your code too, right?

Comment: Yes, fortunately, it did work as intended, I guess the gif isn't loaded when I don't call the ```jumpToFrame()``` function, because when I was trying to get it to work, every time I run the code it'd gave me a black screen.

Comment: I'll explain it in a separate answer, as the current one isn't very specific on the reason for that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> bool QMovie::jumpToFrame(int frameNumber)
>
> Jumps to frame number frameNumber. Returns true on success; otherwise returns false.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie

class APP(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)

#        self.movie = QMovie(r'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Desktop\de.gif')
        self.movie = QMovie(self)                                       # + self
        self.movie.setFileName('D:/_Qt/__Qt/img/Fo2BxBK.gif')           # +
        self.movie.setScaledSize(QSize(300,225))
        self.movie.jumpToFrame(0)                                       # +

        self.label = QLabel(self)                                       # +
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)                                 # +
        
        self.btn = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.btn.setCheckable(True)                                     # +
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.strt)
        self.btn.setGeometry(100,230,150,50)

#        self.label = QLabel(self)
#        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)

        self.show()

    def strt(self, state):                                               # + state
        print("Button pressed", state)
        if state:
            self.movie.start()
            self.btn.setText("Stop")
        else:
            self.movie.stop()
            self.btn.setText("Start")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
demo = APP()
app.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, `jumpToFrame()` only ensures that the first frame is loaded and correctly appears on start, but that's not the exact reason for the behavior the OP asks about.